# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource,

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to run this PHP Function:

```
function makeString() {
    // Create our random string
    $string = "";
    $characters = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, 4)];
    }

    $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM urls WHERE short_url = '{$string}'";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

    if($result['COUNT(*)'] > 0)
    {
        // if it already exists, do it again
         makeString();
    }
    else
    {
        return $string;

        //insert the data
    }
}

makeString();
```

but im getting these errors:

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in /home/charlie/public_html/short/shorten.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/charlie/public_html/short/shorten.php on line 16
```

what do they mean?

all the table/database columns seem okay and there are no reserved words etc...

Comment: Where does `$conn` come from?

Comment: @mario: Doesn't come from anywhere. He's given us the whole function, and it's not defined, thus it's null. Perhaps he's expecting a global variable to work.

Comment: @mario $conn is my DB Connection settings -  this is irrelevant as i am connecting to the database fine

Comment: @user2710234: It's kind of extremely relevant. Look at your warning message. parameter 2 is null. Parameter 2 is `$conn`. Connect the dots.

Comment: Just remove the `$conn` since you say you are already connected you don't really need it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_query parameter error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679622/mysql-query-parameter-error-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$conn` is not available inside scope of function `makeString()` you can either remove it because it's not required if you already connected, or you can pass it as function argument like:

```
makeString($conn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either define your `$conn` or pass it into the function.

```
//Defined Outside of Function
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('database', $link);

//Make argument for connection
function makeString($conn)
{
    //Rest of Function Here
}

//Execute function, passing $link as argument.
$result = makeString($link);
```

or

```
function makeString()
{
    //Define Connection Within Function
    $conn = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'user', 'pass' );
    mysql_select_db('database', $conn);

    //Rest of Function Here
}
```

In any case, straight `mysql` extension is depreciated, look into converting your code to use `mysqli` or `PDO` once you get it working.

[MySQLi Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
[PDO Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)